# R's download.file freezes my R session

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm facing a problem I'm not able to fix at the moment: When I'm trying to install packages (RStudio 1.0.136, R 3.3.3)  my R session freezes. I tracked the problem down to the `utils::download.file` function. The funny thing is: For some URL's it works, for some not. I can download google's and stackoverflow's index.html, when I try yahoo.com R freezes. The same thing happens, when `install.packages` tries to get the package list from CRAN.

I'm behind a proxy, but that was never a problem before and since I can connect to some URL's I guess that's not the problem. Does anyone have an idea what to look for?